# How to append docx file in Golang

Tags: go, docx, file-handling

I want to copy all the contents of a docx file (including its formatting like bold, underline, bullets, paragraphs, etc.) and append it to another docx file.

In this case I want to copy contents from **Source/D1.docx** and append it to **temp.docx**

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./Source/D1.docx")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    file, err := os.OpenFile("temp.docx", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    file.Write(data)
}
```

Comment: The `docx` file type (like all complex file types) has its own format. Appending one file as-is to another likely results in an invalid docx file. You need a library that reads and interprets the `docx` file, and allows extending it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/unidoc/unioffice
New-Item -ItemType Directory unioffice/document/merge
Set-Location unioffice/document/merge
git pull origin pull/448/head
```

Then in the `merge` folder, make this file:

```
package main

import (
   "github.com/unidoc/unioffice/document"
   "os"
   "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
   s := "TestDocument.docx"
   doc0, e := document.Open(s)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer doc0.Close()
   doc1, e := document.Open(s)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer doc1.Close()
   doc0.AddParagraph().AddRun().AddPageBreak()
   if e := doc0.Append(doc1); e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   out := filepath.Join(os.TempDir(), "merged.docx")
   doc0.SaveToFile(out)
}
```

Note this is just for testing, for real code you will want to get a license.

https://github.com/unidoc/unioffice

Comment: For documents in `docx` format, I have a GO library that can set basic styles. It does not require any license or authorization. If the content currently provided meets the needs, you can consider using it. https://github.com/Luna-CY/go-office

Comment: @Luna I dont think you understood the question